# How can I make RSS feeds per author?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss, gatsby

On my Gatsby site, I'm trying to create RSS feeds for each author. However, it's proving to be tricky. The problem is, I can't pass any variable data to the `output` section, which is where my desired RSS path would be. For example: output: `blog/feed-${authorName}-posts.xml`. This would generate an RSS feed for each author, in theory.

Has anyone been successful with this? I appreciate any advice.

EDIT: I'm using the `gatsby-plugin-feed` plugin for building the RSS feed. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-feed/

Here's my code so far:

```js
const blogAuthor = {
  serialize: ({ query: { site, allContentfulAuthor } }) => {
    return allContentfulAuthor.nodes.map(author => {
      return Object.assign(
        {},
        {},
        {
          custom_elements: [
            { 'dc:creator': author.name },
            {
              posts: author.blog___post?.map(post => ({
                title: post.title,
                description: post.description.description,
                date: post.date,
                url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + '/blog/' + post.slug,
              })),
            },
          ],
          description: author.description,
        },
      );
    });
  },
  query: `
    {
      allContentfulAuthor(sort: {order: ASC, fields: name}) {
        nodes {
          name
          description
            blog___post {
            slug
            title
            date
            categories {
              name
            }
            description {
              description
            }
            author {
              name
              description
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  output: `blog/feed-${authorName}-posts.xml`,
  title: `Aiven Blog | ${authorName}`,
  match: `^/blog-${authorName}-posts/`,
};
```

Comment: You don't specify how you're generating your RSS feeds. Seems like you're using a plugin that lacks sufficient configuration. It's probably easier just to generate the feeds using more general purpose libraries and do `fs.writeFile` to write them to disk instead of being hamstrung by a plugin.

Comment: @coreyward Thanks for your comment! You made a good point. I am using a plugin. It's called `gatsby-plugin-feed`. I have just updated the question. I'm new to creating the RSS feeds. You mentioned general purpose libraries and `fs.writeFile`. Do you have any examples to look at? Or do any specific libraries come to mind? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've used [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feed) a bunch.

Comment: The `fs.writeFile` was just what I needed. I followed this example to get me started: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefile-method/.